# Adding data to "multipart/data-form" object

Tags: jsp, servlets

I have a "multipart/form-data" form in a JSP/servlet application. This application is loaded on Apache tomcat 6.31.

What I want to know is can we add new data to the form object received in servlet? If yes then how?

Something like:

1. JSP page has a form where a file has to be uploaded.
2. Once the form is submitted and the data received in servlet we need to add say userid and password to it which we cannot expose in UI layer. Then resubmit that form to another JSP / Servlet with the new data

Answer (score 0):

I would do it as follows:

1. Servlet 1 will received the multipart request.
2. I would decorate the `HTTPServletRequest` using [`HttpServletRequestWrapper`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequestWrapper.html) received in servlet one and return the user and password when the "getParameter" is called on the request. (See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12553491/whats-wrong-with-httpservletresponseaddheader/12553564#12553564) to see a sample decorator of `HttpServletRequest` using `HttpServletRequestWrapper`).
3. RequestDispatcher.forward(decoratedRequest, response) to that JSP/Servlet that would process the data.

> What I want to know is can we add new data to the form object received in servlet?

To answer this question, you can generally have other form controls like textbox, radio, checkbox etc, along with a `FILE` control in a `multipart/form-data` type of form, just in case you are already not aware of this.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirement properly,

you want to add few more parameters to the request object after it reaches to servlet.

you can do this like,

```
request.setAttribute("userId", "xyz");
request.setAttribute("password", "abc");
request.getRequestDispatcher("Path where you want to forward").forward(request, response);
```

You can access the same attribute at the result page.